# Matrix elegant constructor with curly brakets

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to develop a nice basic class Matrix , it's container is a simpler pointer to data_type (template argument);

I'would like to figure out how can i construct my Matrix in this way :

```
Matrix<type> mat = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
```

right now the only way to construct with given an arbitrary number of parameter is using this constructor :

```
//--- construct by list of arguments
template<typename data_type>
template <typename ... Ts>   
constexpr Matrix<data_type>::Matrix(std::size_t row , 
                                    std::size_t col ,
                                    Ts&&... args     ) noexcept : row{row}, columns{col},
                                                                   data{ new data_type[row*col] }

{       
        assert(sizeof...(args) == row*columns );

        std::initializer_list<data_type> il ( { std::forward<Ts>(args)... } );
        std::copy(il.begin(), il.end(), data);
}
```

but for using this I have to use this crap expression in the user-side code :

```
 Matrix<double> m3(3,2,1.12,2.434,3.546546,4.657,5.675675,6.542354);
```

thanks in advance for your precious support !

I've found this solutions.. but i don't know if there is a better way to doing so .... here the completly code (I wrote a matrix class with only this constructor in order to doing some try ) :

```
# include <iostream>

# include <initializer_list>
# include <iterator>




using namespace std;

template <typename data_type>
class Matrix {
    public:  

    constexpr Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<data_type>> rows) {

            size_t row = rows.size() ;
            cout << "Here" << endl;      
            auto il = *(rows.begin()); 
            size_t col = il.size();
            cout << row << ' ' << col << endl;


            size_t i=0;

            size_t n = row * col;

            cout << n << endl;;
            data = new data_type[ n ];
            i=0; 
            for(auto& row : rows )
                  for(auto & r : row){
                        data[i] = r ;
                        i++;
                  }
            for (i=0; i < n ; i++ ) 
                   cout << data[i] << endl;




    }

    private:

    data_type* data;

};





int main(){


      Matrix<int>  mat = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};


   return 0;   
}
```

Comment: What about using nested initializer lists? Something like: template<data_type> Matrix(std::initializer_list <std::initializer_list<data_type>> rows)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this as a programming exercise? If not, any reason you can't use one of the many extremely optimized linear algebra libraries, such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org)?

Comment: not an exercize ... just i want develop my matrix class with special operation included :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename data_type>
class Matrix {
public:

        constexpr Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<data_type>> rows) {
                // Add rows to data
                data.reserve(rows.size());
                for (auto &row : rows)
                        data.push_back(std::vector<data_type>{row});
        }

private:

        // 2-D array-type for storing data
        std::vector<std::vector<data_type>> data;

};

int main() {
        // New matrix:
        //  1 2 3
        //  4 5 6
        Matrix<int> mat = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: looks nice .. but i don't understand .. how then i can manage the index for row and columns ? how to store this data from initialization (the 2 size of the matrix)

Comment: By "manage the index", do you mean you want to be able to get the number of rows and columns?  Do you mind updating your question to show example usage?